# Repeated measures analysis with only two measurement intervals

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I performed assays looking at the toxicity of several insecticides against a insect. To do this, plant leaves were sprayed with insecticides, placed in small cages, and individual insects were exposed to the plant leaves. 
I assessed the mortality of the individual insects at two time points: one and four days after the insects were introduced to the cages.

Would performing a repeated measures one-way ANOVA be the most appropriate method for analyzing this data? My questioning this approach stems from the fact that there are only two intervals in which the data was collected (it seems that most repeated measures are performed on at least 3 observations), and the time elapsed between the intervals (in relation to the start of the experiment) isn't the same (based on my basic understanding of repeated measures, the intervals would ideally be the same).

I guess the only other approach I can think of taking is performing a two-way ANOVA in which I treat the assessment date as a fixed effect in the model, but this doesn't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fine place to start.  All of applied statistics is a bit of a compromise to start the process, unless you have done very extensive experimental design.  For more on ANOVA and possible issues, see: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/one-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php

Really, as they point out, you are doing a 2 sample t-test.  But that really doesn't matter; ANOVA and regression sort of 'collapse' into those simpler tests if things are simple enough or set up right, and it is much easier (in my mind).

By the way, absent a really solid experimental design, few datasets will meet all six of their criteria.  But you have to start somewhere.

The technical glitch you are going to run into isn't that an equal number of days isn't between exposure, measurement 1, and measurement 2.  It is that any insect that dies before measurement 1 automatically isn't in measurement 2.  Depending on what you want to find, you may want group two  to be the percent that died since measurement 1, and group 1 the percent that dies up and until measurement 1 (or something like that).

Comment: Thank you! I meant to include this in my original post (and have now), but I guess the only other approach I can think of taking is performing a two-way ANOVA in which I treat the assessment date as a fixed effect in the model, but this doesn't seem correct to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am still not quite sure exactly what data you have and are trying to think through, but think of it as two 'treatments': die fast and die slow.  They aren't really treatments.  Classic ANOVA would have one group get d dose of 1 unit, a second group a dose of 2 units, a third group 3 units, and then look for meaningful variation across them.  Here you are abusing ANOVA a bit, but I think it will give you the answer. You could also set this up as a regression, possibly using dummy variables, which might be more intuitive.